# Цвет заменяющего текста в инпуте

Tags: html, css

У меня стоит белый текст в поиске :

```
.inp-white[type=text]::-webkit-input-placeholder { color: #eee; }
.inp-white[type=text]::-moz-placeholder { color: #eee; }
.inp-white[type=text]:-moz-placeholder { color: #eee; }
.inp-white[type=text]:-ms-input-placeholder { color: #eee; }
```

Как сделать чтобы тот текст, который я ввожу, был тоже белым, а не тот который стоит по дефолту (серый)?

Comment: .inp-white[type=text] {color:#fff;}, не?

Comment: Точно) благодарю!!!

Answer (score 1):

```css
html,
body {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  background: #000;
}

.inp-white[type=text] {
  color: #fff;
  background: transparent;
  border: #fff solid 1px;
  margin: 20px;
}

.inp-white[type=text]::-webkit-input-placeholder {
  color: #eee;
}

.inp-white[type=text]::-moz-placeholder {
  color: #eee;
}

.inp-white[type=text]:-moz-placeholder {
  color: #eee;
}

.inp-white[type=text]:-ms-input-placeholder {
  color: #eee;
}
```

```html
<input type="text" class="inp-white" placeholder="Ваше имя" />
```